# setting column to not null based on condition oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a table with column A and column B.  I would like to make column A null-able if column B value is '123' and make it NOT NULL if column B is anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such thing as conditional nullability.  But, you can have a `NULL` value check:

```
create table t (
    . . . ,
    a int,
    b varchar2(255),
    constraint chk_t_a check ( (b <> '123' and a is not null) or (b <> '123'))
);
```

If `b` can take on `NULL` values, then you need to also take that into account.

Note:  If you want `a` to always be `NULL` *only when* `b = '123'` then use:

```
create table t (
    . . . ,
    a int,
    b varchar2(255),
    constraint chk_t_a check ( not (b = '123' and a is not null) )
);
```

`check` constraints pass even when the resulting value is `NULL` -- unlike `WHERE` and `CASE WHEN` logic.  So, this works even when `b` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression  :

```
select (case when colb <> 123 then cola end) as cola, t.colb
from table t;
```